# Python3 check Twython Tweet less than 140 characters with len()

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twython, raspberry-pi2

I am very new to Python and Raspberry Pi.

My goal: as part of my jump right in a build a Raspberry Pi and learn some Python, I'm planning to build a a weather station. As part of that, it will tweet the weather. While this might not be the final code that will be used. This is helping me learn. Which is why I'm posting this question.

I have put together a code from various sources to post to Twitter with Twython. The code (see below) works well. I had to use python3 to not get an SSL error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

#tweetStr = "Tweet goes here, limit 140 characters"
tweetStr = input("Type your Tweet: ")


#Your Twitter Application keys
apiKey = 'apiKey'
apiSecret = 'apiSecret'
accessToken = 'accessToken'
accessTokenSecret = 'accessTokenSecret'

api = Twython(apiKey,apiSecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret)
try:
    api.update_status(status=tweetStr)
except TwythonError as Error:
    print (Error)

print ("Tweeted: ", tweetStr)
```

This works the way I like. Asks for input. If it works it prints to screen the tweet as a confirmation it worked. However, I would like to add the ability to check the user input to verify that it is 140 characters or less. If less than 141, than carry on, if more than 140 charter, return an error saying you've entered too many characters. I will be using text tweets only, no links.

I can get the following to work on its own. However, I 'm not sure how to  get it to work with the above. (Note: I'm using <15 instead of <141 to test and not have to type more than 140 characters). I do not want it to delete what's more than 140, but just return an error to try again.

```
tweetStr = input("Tweet: ")
if len(tweetStr) < 10:
  print (tweetStr)
else:
  print ('too long')
```

I have tried the following, but with no luck:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

#tweetStr = "Tweet goes here, limit 140 character"
tweetStr = input("Type your Tweet: ")

#Your Twitter Application keys
apiKey = 'apiKey'
apiSecret = 'apiSecret'
accessToken = 'accessToken'
accessTokenSecret = 'accessTokenSecret'

api = Twython(apiKey,apiSecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret)

if len(tweetStr) < 15:
    try:
        api.update_status(status=tweetStr)
    except TwythonError as Error:
        print (Error)
else:
      print ('Too long use less than 141 characters')

print ("Tweeted: ", tweetStr)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Maybe there is a totally different and easier way to do the same thing with Twython.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: When I try the last code in my question. It prompts me for a tweet with "Type your Tweet: ". I am just typing "test" and then return. I get the following error:      `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tweet.py", line 6, in <module>
    tweetStr = input("Type your Tweet: "
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined"`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to piece together an answer on my own.

```
#! /usr/bin/ python3
import sys
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

#Your tweet, ask for user input
tweetStr = input('Type your Tweet: ')

#check for twitter input limit, return error if over 140
if len(tweetStr) > 140:
    print('Error! You exceeded 140 Characters. Please try again.')
    sys.exit()

# Your Twitter Application keys
apiKey = 'apiKey'
apiSecret = 'apiSecret'
accessToken = 'accessToken'
accessTokenSecret = 'accessTokenSecret'

api = Twython(apiKey,apiSecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret)

#send your tweet or return Twython error
try:
    api.update_status(status=tweetStr)
except TwythonError as Error:
    print (Error)
#print back your tweet, likely succeeded
print ('Tweeted: ',tweetStr)
```

Even though I called python3 in the #!, for some reason  something changed on my Pi and I have to run  with:

```
python3 filename.py
```

Originally, I could just run with:

```
python filename.py
```

Thanks for looking.